# Apache tomcat troubleshooting on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat

I have set up apache tomcat6.0 and spring framework along with m2eclipse on eclipse helios, However when i go under Windows preferences in Eclipse under Server Runtime and add apachev6.0, i click the next button and it just freezes any Idea. One more thing I have an error everytime I open eclipse saying web DOM service has an error and that spring uaa has an error, I tried going into my eclipse.ini file and adding a -clean and -refresh but still didn't work. Any ideas? I am only in the set up stages and have not started to code yet? Following this guys tutorials. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X8IN5zvLCTI
The installation part for my error in the video starts around 4:40.
I basically followed his entire tutorial. Don;t know what went wrong. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Helios is a *very* old version of Eclipse, 4 major releases behind). Try using a more recent version.

Comment: thanks would you recommend Luna the most recent one? btw, is tomcat 6.0 good enough or 7.0 is needed. Thanks.

Comment: I'd recommend going with the latest of both unless there is a specific requirement not to. Be aware, though, that tutorials written with a certain version may not be 100% accurate or appropriate for later versions.